# can i get iPhone's Built in calendar's event in my application?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, calendar

Is it possible that, i can select date on iPhone's in built calendar and its event can be fetched to my custom application, using which i could send notification from my server to the application on dates selected from iPhone's calendar?

Comment: You probably can yeah, but it sounds like your trying to do something the calendar already does for you?

Comment: @Scriptable , I want to get notification from my own server with content i want in notification. so i am asking about this feature. can you please tell how is that possible or any link for guidance.

Comment: You need to use EventKit if I remember rightly, but it is too broad for here: See this [article](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/05/14/beginners-guide-to-eventkit-in-swift-requesting-permission/)

Comment: @Scriptable, Thanks a lot for the link.

Comment: You're asking two things here: 1) how to access the user's Calendar and 2) how to send a push notification. Both of these things are possible. You haven't noted what you've tried or where you've looked for further information. You should be able to find multiple tutorials for both of these topics.